# Is there any Visual Studio Extension that removes the resource strings and replace it with actual strings values that was part of resource?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, resources, embedded-resource

As title suggest, I am looking for a Visual Studio Extension that lets me remove some of the strings that are in the resources file back in to where it belongs in the code.

I desire this because someone in our projects tossed in the strings that are in the code that deals with xml nodes or paths.

Because we use all the strings that are in resource file as strings to localize, having strings that are desired to be translated in there causes disaster.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html)

It has the feature "Inline Resource" which "deletes a resource entry from a resource file and substitutes all its usages with the original string."